# Is there some flags for gcc to avoid link with unused shared libraries?

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization

```
echo "void main(){}" |gcc -xc -lm -lpthread -o test - && ldd test
```

Here is an example. I don't use any math function in fact. But gcc still links with **libm.so** finally. 
Are there any optimization flags to tell gcc not to link with **libm.so** in such case?

Comment: I have tried -flto flag, but no effect.

Comment: I do not understand, why are you using `-lm` if you do not want to link with *libm.so* ? _gcc_ just follows your request, you explicitly ask it to link with _libm.so_ so it does. You want the optimization flag `-IdontKnowWhatIwantSoDontTakeIntoAccountTheOptionsIgive` ?

Comment: OK. So will libm.so be loaded into memory when I run test program?

Comment: yes it is, as _ldd_ says, just rename that lib and you will see you cannot start the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find out the result finally. -Wl,--as-needed is for this case.

Comment: `--as-needed`  is the default on some distros (Debian, Ubuntu,...) and not on others, apparently including yours.

Answer (score 0):

In

> echo "void main(){}" |gcc -xc -lm -lpthread -o test - && ldd test

the `-lm` explicitly asks for to link with *libm.so*, *gcc* as a *good boy* just follows your request.

May be you have a good reason to link with, *gcc* / *ld* cannot know why you do that and cannot decide by themselves to not follow your request, and there is no option `-dontDoWhatIaskYouToDo` ^^

If you do not want to link with that lib do not ask to link with it

Comment: For reference: `-dontDoWhatIaskYouToDo` documentation: This flag instructs the compiler and linker to not comply with the user requests (flags). As a result the compiler will ignore the request for `-dontDoWhatIaskYouToDo`. So in effect this tells the compiler to actually do what the user ask to do. The effect this flag has on all other flags is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @bolov exactly ^^

Comment: Maybe you are correct. But in real complex projects, a program may be linked with many other libraries by pre-defined rules. I mean that most libraries are not added by the programmer, but the library provider. So if the linker can check whether an executable really need a library before linking with it, then we can make a minimum dependence program. I think the checking is realizable, based on symbol reference